# Find CloudFront Distribution associated with S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have looked in to AWS SDK documentation trying to find a way to get the CloudFront Distributions associated with a specific S3 bucket, but no luck so far.

I need to save some images that are only accessible throw CloudFront distribution domain name. I wanted to fetch this dynamically, since this url can change.

Knowing the name of the bucket how can I get this URL using the sdk?

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

To the date, I don't think there's a direct way to achieve that but with the AWS SDK you can do it as follows to find the distribution id from an S3 origin (or any other origin) in Javascript:

```
    const params = {};
    cloudfront.listDistributions(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        }
        else {
            const distributionItems = data.DistributionList.Items;
            const distributionByOrigin = distributionItems.find(item => item.Origins.Items.find(originItem => originItem.DomainName === 'your.origin.domain.name.here'));
            console.log(distributionByOrigin.Id);
    });
```

Alternatively, the same can be achieved if instead you have an alias:

```
const params = {};
cloudfront.listDistributions(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    }
    else {
        const distributionItems = data.DistributionList.Items;
        const distributionByAlias = distributionItems.find(item => item.Aliases.Items.find(aliasItem => aliasItem === 'your.url.alias.here'));
        console.log(distributionByAlias.Id);
    }
});
```